# Swift - can't call public function from child view controller? ViewController has no member error?

Tags: ios, swift

Alright, so in the past I have been able to create new child view controllers like this and then be able to call functions within them easily:

```
let v : ResultsViewController = ResultsViewController (nibName: "ResultsViewController", bundle: nil)
self.addChildViewController(v)
        self.view.addSubview(v.view)
        v.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        v.view.frame = self.view.bounds

v.doSomething(self)
```

Where doSomething was a public func in the Results VC class with any object as sender.

I am attempting to do the exact same thing while creating the VC slightly different but am getting the error [image]

With this:

at class level I have  `var skip = UIViewController()`

Then in a function:

```
skip = Results2ViewController (nibName: "Results2ViewController", bundle: nil)
        self.addChildViewController(skip)
        self.view.addSubview(skip.view)
        skip.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        skip.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(skip.view)
        //make sure accept is there
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(circleView)

        skip.definesPresentationContext = false;
        skip.view.frame.origin.x -= self.view.bounds.width
skip.setIdeaLabels(self) //ERROR
```

Where in the Results 2 class I have like always

```
public func setIdeaLabels(sender: AnyObject)
```

I have to write it this way and not just declaring skip as `let skip = Results2ViewController (nibName: "Results2ViewController", bundle: nil)` because I reuse this skip variable elsewhere and the variable would go out of scope.

Why can't I call a function in my child view controller? Why doesn't it have member?

Comment: try `skip = Results2ViewController (nibName: "Results2ViewController", bundle: nil) as! Results2ViewController` I think the error is because it's looking for the method in the standard UIViewController class where yours is extended even though it is still technically a UIViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare `var skip = UIViewController()`, then `skip` is implicitly typed as `UIViewController`. You can't change the type of a variable after it is declared - `Results2ViewController` is a `UIViewController`, so it "fits" in `skip`. But the compiler still sees it as being a `UIViewController` so it doesn't have the methods of a `Results2ViewController`.

You can set the instance variable to have the correct type, you can cast it when you need to call that method or you can use a local reference of the correct type to call that method.

1) Replace `var skip = UIViewController()` with `var skip : Results2ViewController?` Notice how I made `skip` optional and did not initialize it to anything. You could also use `var skip = Results2ViewController (nibName: "Results2ViewController", bundle: nil)` but I assume there is some reason you aren't doing that in the first place.

2) Cast `skip` before calling `setIdeaLabels`.

```
skip = Results2ViewController (nibName: "Results2ViewController", bundle: nil)
var results = skip as! Results2ViewController;
results.setIdeaLabels(self);
```

3) Initialize it locally, then set it to `skip` when you're done.

```
let results = Results2ViewController (nibName: "Results2ViewController", bundle: nil)
results.setIdeaLabels(self);
skip = results;
```

Options 2 and 3 are pretty similar. I'd go with 3 purely because I'm not a fan of using extra casts. I like 1 but it leaves you with a lot of potential for unwrapping an optional all over the place.